# Print content after function ends his work

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

here's my problem: I have to print same times after a function has done his work to show differents content in page. I used the promise object to get when the function ends his work.
One print for each loop.
I retrieve the array via json to the elements must be print to print one per time.
The code is here

```
$('#prev_print').on("click", (function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'json/get.php?multi=' + $("#prev_id").val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    encode: true
  }).then(function(data) {
    if ((data)["success"] === true) {
      $.each((data)["multi"], function(i, n) {
        prev_edit(n).then(function() {
          window.print();
        });
      });
    }
  });
}));


function prev_edit(prev_id) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'json/get.php?t=2&p=' + prev_id,
    dataType: 'json',
    encode: true
  }).then(function(data) {
    var prom;
    //some operations to show the retrieved data from json
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#cli_header").offset().top }, 'slow');
    $("#risultato").show();
    prom = $("#preventivo_edit").show("slow").promise();
    return prom;
  });
};
```

It prints many times to the lenght of the array but  not wait when function finish his work

Comment: Please, provide an indented code

Comment: Please explain problem and expected behavior in more detail. Do you want the loop to complete and print once only?

Comment: i want to loop and print every loop